# Getting rid of the None

Tags: python-3.x, class

I am having issues getting rid of the None in the output. I tried to assign variables but still, it went in vain. Any help is highly appreciated.

P.S - The execution must be print(rect1.get_picture()).
It cannot be just rect1.getpicture().
It's part of the requirement

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self,width,height):
       self.width = width
       self.height=height

    def get_picture(self):
        def draw():
            for j in range(self.height):
                for i in range(self.width):
                    print("*", end="")
                print()

        if self.height>50 or self.width>50:
            return ("Too big for picture")

        else:
            return draw()
rect1 =Rectangle(width=5,height=5)
print(rect1.get_picture())
```

Comment: Function `draw` is not returning anything. You need it to "accumulate" a string instead of printing it, and at the end, return that string.

Comment: You can change this function to a single line: `return ('*' * self.width + '\n') * self.height`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `draw` function should return a string rather than print it. Note that you can always print the result.

```
def draw():
    for j in range(self.height):
        for i in range(self.width):
            print("*", end="")
        print()
```

changes to

```
def draw():
    rectangle = ""
    for j in range(self.height):
        for i in range(self.width):
            rectangle += "*"
        rectangle += "\n"
    return rectangle
```

I kept your two loops so that you see the changes easily, but as someone said in the comments it's possible to use multiplications instead.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, you need to make the `draw` function actually return something you can print.

For example:

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
       self.width = width
       self.height= height

    def get_picture(self):
        def draw():
            return "\n".join("*"*self.width for _ in range(self.height))

        if self.height > 50 or self.width > 50:
            return ("Too big for picture")
        else:
            return draw()

rect1 = Rectangle(width=7, height=5)
print(rect1.get_picture())
```

produces

```
*******
*******
*******
*******
*******
```

In order to make things a little more OO, I'd let the Rectangle print itself, abiding by Python's printing protocol

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self,width,height):
       self.width = width
       self.height= height

    def __str__(self):
        if self.height > 50 or self.width > 50:
            return ("Picture too big for printing")
        return "\n".join("*"*self.width for _ in range(self.height))

rect1 =Rectangle(width=7, height=5)
print(rect1)
```